# The numbers with decimal are reversed. How to correct them?

Tags: excel

I have got an excel datasheet in which the values seem to be reversed. For example, 78.32 is shown as 23;78 or 0.1868 has become 8681;0. Is there any way to quickly transform them into correct values? There are thousands of them and I couldn't find any useful guidance on the web to correct these numbers.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're value is in cell `A1` ...

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(";",A1)),A1,NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(";",A1)+1,1000)&"."&ReverseString(LEFT(A1,FIND(";",A1)-1))))
```

... you'll also need this supporting piece of VBA Code.

```
Public Function ReverseString(ByVal strText As String) As String
    ReverseString = StrReverse(strText)
End Function
```

If you've a later version of Excel that support `TEXTJOIN` ...

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(";",A1)),A1,NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(";",A1)+1,1000)&"."&TEXTJOIN("",1,MID(LEFT(A1,FIND(";",A1)-1),{10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1},1))))
```

I find it to be the easiest way but there may be someone with a better option.